# Software Center - some installed programs not listed

Tags: software-center

Since few week Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I already had lightworks and librecad installed in previous version (18.04).
They work properly in ubuntu 20.04.
I mentioned that these programs are not listed in Software Center / installed programs?
When I go in Software Center to "exploring" and type in the search box by example "lightworks" I get "no software found"?
Strange, isn't it? certainly to get updates or remove this software for instance ...

Comment: So, software not installed from the Software Center is not listed in the SC..., sounds about right too me. What can we do for you? Do you have a question to ask?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Software (Software Center) application is not omniscient. Linux systems do not have a central registry of all software.

Ubuntu Software only knows about deb and snap software.

It generally doesn't know about pip, AppImage, flatpak, brew, or other package systems, nor about manually-compiled software, nor about any scripts you may written or downloaded. Recognizing some additional software (like AppImage) can be added by extensions.

Comment: Dear user535733,
You're probably right about the 'not-omniscient'. And maybe further on, they're will be more software attached to the center. For now it works fine, and I will look and search again in this forum if necesarry (removing software, updates, ...).
Thanks for you reply.
Kind regards, Steven

Answer (score 0):

If your system is fresh, then you might have to open up the terminal by doing `Ctrl + Alt + T` and follow the steps.

1. do `sudo su` to get to the super user (just in case if there will be any permission problems)
2. do `sudo apt full-update`
3. after the full-update command is completed, do `sudo apt full-upgrade`
4. do `sudo apt autoremove` to clear any unnecessary or unused files that the system may not need. After that complete steps 2 and 3.
5. for extra measures, do `sudo apt autoclean` this clears your cache which may cause that issue (cache files are files that store data to load faster. too much of that may cause problems).
6. You might have to restart since certain updates will take an effect after restarting.

I hope this helps since i had a similar problem in older versions such as 16.04 but 20.04 is relatively new. So the developers will pickup on that and try to solve it if that's an error. OR they might update the Software Centre so that it will be more compatible with other file types.

Btw. run the built in software with the name which goes along the lines of  `Softawre installer` for executing .AppImages. I have done that to install a game using that .AppImage file which worked as a result of that action.

Again, i hope this helps. And good luck with finding out the solution if this one didn't quite help.

Comment: Dear Mr. C. Soldier,
I tried the 'sudo's' but no result.
The programs are running fine.
I keep the Appimages in mind.
thanks for reply
kind regards, Steven

Comment: maybe use dpkg? It might help. but im not sure. I dont use AppImages that often